# Wrap lines of text to a specified character length limit with support for ansi color codes

Tags: shell, terminal, colors, word-wrap, ansi-escape

I want to wrap some text to fit my terminal. I currently use `fold -s -w 80` but this counts ansi color codes which makes it wrap colorful lines prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# brew install cpanm
cpanm App::ansifold
# cpanm -V # to find install dir
# /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.1/bin/ansifold
# use just like fold: `ansifold -s -w 80`
```

Example screenshots of `ansifold` wrapping text correctly:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26164109)

Comment: @ChrisCatignani This is a complete answer. It works great.

Comment: I agree...your answer was flagged as a Low Quality Post. I was reviewing it and saw that since you asked the original question...you should have just added an addendum to your original post...though its not too uncommon to answer your own question.